# Gold & silver cards

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Out of 52 cards, we have 4 gold and 48 silver. We pick 2 cards randomly out of the 52. What is the probability that we picked 1 or 2 gold cards?

How the above can be solved with conditional probability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine that we are picking the cards one at a time. We can get $1$ or $2$ gold in two (disjoint) ways:

(i) The first card we pick is gold or

(ii) The first card we pick is silver, but the second is gold.

The probability of (i) is $\frac{4}{52}$.

For (ii), the probability the first is silver is $\frac{48}{52}$. The *conditional probability* that the second is gold, **given** the first was silver, is $\frac{4}{51}$. For if the first card picked was silver, there are $51$ cards left, of which $4$ are gold.

Thus the probability of (ii) is $\frac{48}{52}\cdot \frac{4}{51}$.

Finally,add, and if you wish, simplify.

Comment: Thanks! Btw, I guess I can call you "Maths" Jon Skeet! :P

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Pick 1 gold card: $2\binom{4}{1}\binom{48}{1}$ number of ways. Pick two gold cards: $\binom{4}{2}$ number of ways. Pick any 2 cards: $\binom{52}{2}$.

Comment: How the above can be solved with conditional probability?

Comment: I guess I misunderstood your question: did you mean that either the first selected card is gold or the second selected card is gold?

Comment: Yes. I was looking for a conditional probability solution but your answer was ok, that's why i up-voted you.